# ROS Answers SE migration: hokuyo 30lx

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can this laser hokuyo 30lx  use for obstacle identification to avoid or just a range finder
any help please ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42148/hokuyo-30lx/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on 2012-08-23**:
dose the node in ROS provide this functionality

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-23**:
There are nodes that do, like move_base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can use any range finder for obstacle avoidance.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1